# Creating a Open File Dialog Function to be used multiple times

Tags: vb.net

I have this piece of code that I would like to make it into a function so I can reuse it by changing some parameters.

So this is what I have so far

```
Sub OpenFiles(InFile As IO.StreamReader, verifytheFileName As String,dialogBoxTitle As String)
    Dim result As DialogResult
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Try
        dialogBox1.Title = dialogBoxTitle
        dialogBox1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*" 
        result = dialogBox1.ShowDialog 'Open This Dialog Box
        FilePath = dialogBox1.FileName 'Gets the Path of the file and stores it in File Path Varible
        FileName = dialogBox1.SafeFileName 'Gets the name of the file and stores it in File Name Varible

        If Not FileName = verifytheFileName Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select " &verifytheFileName)
            dialogBox1.Reset()
        Else
            InFile = IO.File.OpenText(FilePath)
        End If                  
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
    End Try

End Sub
```

So the only thing I am unable to do is to change the `dialogBox1` text in to `dialogBox2` or `dialogBox3`.

Please advice on how can I get this done

Comment: Why do you need to change it? It would work just fine as is, unless you want to open several FileOpen dialogs at the same time which does not make sense and is only possible from multiple threads.

Comment: i have several buttons which open Different types of files

Comment: You can't press them at once anyway. Just pass the `Filter` as a parameter like you already pass `Title`.

Comment: ahh danm yes u are correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the dialogbox in parameters function

```
Sub OpenFiles(InFile As IO.StreamReader, verifytheFileName As String,dialogBoxTitle As String, dialogBox1 as System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog)
Dim result As DialogResult
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String

Try
    dialogBox1.Title = dialogBoxTitle
    dialogBox1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*" 
    result = dialogBox1.ShowDialog 'Open This Dialog Box
    FilePath = dialogBox1.FileName 'Gets the Path of the file and stores it in File Path Varible
    FileName = dialogBox1.SafeFileName 'Gets the name of the file and stores it in File Name Varible

    If Not FileName = verifytheFileName Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select " &verifytheFileName)
        dialogBox1.Reset()
    Else
        InFile = IO.File.OpenText(FilePath)
    End If                  
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
End Try

End Sub
```